# Is it valid syntax in ECMAScript to surround each case in a switch / case statement with curly braces?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm never entirely comfortable with formatting `switch`/`case` statements in JavaScript. Given the following:

```
switch (myVariable) {

  case ('a'):
  console.log('apple');
  break;

  case ('b'):
  console.log('banana');
  break;

  case ('c'):
  console.log('cherry');
  break;

  default:
  console.log('pineapple);
}
```

I feel that the lines after the `case` declaration *ought* to be indented.

But if they *were* indented, there would then be a peculiar-looking two-column gap between the last line of the last case and the closing curly brace of the `switch` block.

It has just occurred to me that I might surround the code of each `case` within their own curly braces.

I suspected this might be **invalid**, but my browser is happy with it, Prettier is happy with it and, surprisingly, even JSHint is content with this formatting.

Here is an example of what I'm describing:

```
switch (myVariable) {

  case ('a'): {
    console.log('apple');
    break;
  }

  case ('b'): {
    console.log('banana');
    break;
  }

  case ('c'): {
    console.log('cherry');
    break;
  }

  default: {
    console.log('pineapple);
  }
}
```

This formatting enables code indentation without introducing the two-column gap.

But surely this isn't valid ECMAScript syntax, is it?

Comment: Why not just try it and find out if it throws a syntax error or not? (It's valid.)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I'm aware that what is sometimes accepted by JS-interpreters in browsers doesn't necessarily conform with ECMAScript proper. I can test JS in the browser, but I can only determine what is right in ECMAScript by reading specs etc.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe, appreciated. This is the relevant section: https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-switch-statement, though, as far as I can tell, it has nothing to say about using curly braces with each `case`.

Comment: I don't know what you were expecting to see - the official specs including "Yes Rounin you can have braces here :)"? They say what's valid case, and that includes the possibility of blocks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - in the answer below, CertainPerformance cites precisely the kind of official confirmation I was looking to find (but had, thus far, failed to locate): _"A statement may be a BlockStatement"_. Alongside that, I very much appreciate the link you posted above. Thanks again.

Comment: this is very common in my experience, and not for formatting - sometimes you need to declare variables in `case` clauses, and you would really want these to be in their own scope, which a `{...}` block creates (assuming you're using `let` or `const` rather than `var`!), but a `case` statement on its own most certainly does not!

Comment: Yes, I see. That absolutely makes sense, @RobinZigmond. Thank you for adding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the syntax, a single "case" is called a [CaseClause](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CaseClause). A CaseClause is componsed of:

> ```
> case Expression: StatementList
> ```

A StatementList [is composed of](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-StatementList) a StatementListItem.

A StatementListItem [is either](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-StatementListItem) a statement or declaration.

A statement [may be](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Statement) a BlockStatement.

A block statement is [a plain block](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-BlockStatement) - which is a block which contains a StatementList:

> ```
> { StatementList }
> ```

So yes, it's valid syntax.